# Integrating google-drive with Ionic android application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-drive-android-api, drive

[I also tried, but nothing work  I'm using $cordovaOauth for google authentication.. any thoughts ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVbwF.png)

Comment: Have a look at this link - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/integrating-google-drive-with-ionic-project/27921 Hope it helps

Comment: "I also tried". Where is your code?